# How to get rid of wireworms in garden plot

Tags: pest-control, potatoes, pesticide, carrots

Has anyone had success removing wireworms from their garden and do you have any tips? I've looked some online and it seems like baiting them with potatoes is the best solution. I am not opposed to pesticides.

We have a large plot and like to plant potatoes every year. We practice crop rotation, but have noticed wire worm damage in our potatoes this year. We started planting carrots two or three years ago, so I was wondering if planting carrots was ruining the benefits were were previously getting from rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go; try this article.  The best way to deal with any of these problems is always know thy enemy.  Pesticides usually do far more harm than are helpful.  See if this article helps you with these guys.  There IS a BT for beetles SOMEWHERE.  I've no idea why they've not produced this stuff.  It is a toxin made by a bacterium call Bacillus thuringiensis so when the insect eats it they feel so full they stop eating and actually starve to death.

There is a BT for caterpillars, mosquitoes/flies and one for beetles.  I don't know if it is for the adult beetle or its larvae.  I would think the BT for caterpillars which works for larvae would work just fine without making your ecosystem get out of wack.  But that will take a bit more investigation.

This article looks like a good read...let us know what you think.  You obviously know the language, here!! [wireworm](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/crops/facts/00-047.htm)